# pdftex: SVG not found

Tags: graphics, errors, svg

I'm trying to use svg graphics in my big latex document. I followed other posts and included the svg and the amsmath package. And used the following to test it:

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \includesvg{Images/Evaluation/Comparison/atlanta/SuccessRate}
    \caption{svg image}
\end{figure}
```

Unfortunately, I get three error messages for the line where I include the svg:
2x "LaTeX Error: File .../SuccessRate not found. [...]"
1x "LaTeX Error: File .../SuccessRate.pdf_tex not found. [...]"
Especially the second one is weird becaus I don't even want to find a .pdf_tex file. The svg-file is in the specified directory and adding .svg to the path in includesvg doesn't help either.

I'm using Miktex and Texmaker on Windows 8.1. My document class is scrbook and not article as in the other posts I saw.

Comment: using svg this way requires you to allow external programs (--shell-escape in texlive, not sure about miktex) and to have inkscape available to do the conversion. It's easier really to just use any convenient tool to save your svg as pdf and then include that using `\includegraphics`

Comment: Okay, I'll do that then!